# mysqli union arrange results per talbe

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using a mysqli union to search the database like so:

```
$search = security($_POST['search']);
$search_val = "%{$search}%";
$search_disp = '';

if($searchQ = $db->prepare(
    "(SELECT name AS `name1` FROM `table1` WHERE name LIKE ? LIMIT 8)
    UNION 
     (SELECT heading AS `name2` FROM `table2` WHERE heading LIKE ? LIMIT 8)
    ")){
        if($searchQ->bind_param("ss",$search_val,$search_val)){
            if($searchQ->execute()){
               $searchQ->store_result();

               if($searchQ->num_rows){
                  $searchQ->bind_result($search_result);
                  while($searchQ->fetch()){
                      $search_disp.='
                          <div>'.$search_result.'</div>
                      ';
                  } 
               }
            }
            else{echo '$db->error' exit();}
        }
        else{echo '$db->error' exit();}
    }
    else{echo '$db->error' exit();}

    echo $search_disp; exit();
```

What I dont know how to achieve is display a different result depending on the table it came from since I'm fetching both results as the same varialbe ($search_result), for example:

```
if(result from table one){
    $search_disp.='
        <div class="talbe1">'.$search_result.'</div>
    ';
}
else if(result from table two){
    $search_disp.='
        <div class="talbe2">'.$search_result.'</div>
    ';
}
```

Can someone please help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add additional row `tbl` to result set and then use it:

```
(SELECT 'table1' as tbl, name FROM `table1` WHERE name LIKE ? LIMIT 8)
UNION 
(SELECT 'table2' as tbl, heading AS name FROM `table2` WHERE heading LIKE ? LIMIT 8)
```

Comment: Thank that will work, though I was wondering if theres a way to do it from inside the query without adding an aditional row.

Comment: Nope, because `UNION`  combines the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set.